# Stop MySQL service windows

Tags: mysql, shutdown, restart

I am developing a website and need to refresh data. Therefore MySQL must be stopped.
How can I stop the service?

When I look at control panel services it is started without stop or restart option.

Comment: ACtually, why do you even need to stop a server to refresh your data?

Comment: To start : net start mysql

Type in CMD with run as administrator: net stop mysql

Answer (score 73):

**On Windows**

If you are using Windows Open the Command Prompt and type

To Stop MySQL Service:

```
net stop MySQL80
```

To Start MySQL Service:

```
net start MySQL80
```

**On Linux**

```
# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
# /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
# /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Fedora / Red Hat also support this:

```
# service mysqld start
# service mysqld stop
# service mysqld restart
```

Also Systemd based distrubutions (like Ubuntu or Arch Linux) support this:

```
# systemctl start mysql
# systemctl stop mysql
# systemctl restart mysql
```

I know this answer is late but i hope it helps for some one.

Comment: If on CENTOS7 the service command is replaced by systemctl start/stop/restart <service name>

Comment: `The service name is invalid. More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185`

Comment: On Windows for version 5.7 specific it is MySQL57

Comment: On Windows 10 with MySQL 8.0 it is MySQL80. Run from terminal: NET STOP MySQL80, then NET START MySQL80

Comment: For me the service name is just "mysql"

Answer (score 48):

You can set its startup type to manual in services.msc. This way it will not start automatically unless required.  Simply get the name of the service from services.msc as shown here:

[image]

You can create batch files to start and stop the service fairly easily as well. Now use this name in batch files.

Your start.bat:

```
net start "mysql"
```

And in your stop.bat:

```
net stop "mysql"
```

Answer (score 17):

The Top Voted Answer is out of date. I just installed MySQL 5.7 and the service name is now `MySQL57` so the new command is

`net stop MySQL57`

Comment: This worked for me and I had to run mine as admin, just a note to whomever it may help.

Comment: It depends on what version you install and it is also possible to give the service a custom name.

Comment: dont forget to run console as admin

Comment: The 2nd most voted answer gives nice screenshots of where to look for the name in services. It seems like it should just consistently be named MySQL instead of trying to stick a version number on there. My service was simply called MySQL, but I'm using an older version of MySQL Server.

Answer (score 13):

Start Powershell as administrator and run:

```
net start [MySQL-service-name]
```

**Find the service name:**

run 'services.msc', look for MySQL and click on properties

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If MySQL 57.

```
net start MySQL57
```

OR

```
net stop MySQL57
```

Comment: This worked for me with powershell as an administrator on my windows development server.

Answer (score 6):

```
net stop MySQL*
```

or

```
mysqld stop
```

or

```
mysql stop
```

in the window's command line prompt.

<*> if you're using windows XP, you need the name of your service, which can be obtained doing this: (credits [@Atli](http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/884724-facing-error-starting-stopping-mysql-service-command-line-mode))

> right click the "My Computer" shortcut in the Start menu, select
>   "Manage", click "Services" in the "Services and applications" group.
>   And then search the list of services until you find the MySQL service.
>
> Then you can start [or stop] the service by using that name. It is can sometimes
>   be called "mysql5" or "mysql51", or something like that. Depends on
>   who installed it.

Comment: Neither stops the server on XP. 1) `net stop MySQL` => "system error 1060.". 2) `mysqld stop` => "2013-04-12 17:22:50 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_times
tamp server option (see documentation for more details)". The server is still running. 3) `mysql stop` => "ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'stop'". The server war started with "mysqld --console".

Comment: @Green. Exactly my experience running those three commands! I used Windows 8. That being said, running `net stop <name_of_mysql_service>` does work when the command window was opened 'As Administrator'.

Comment: looks like, starting command line with "Run as Administrator" mode worked for me

Answer (score 6):

For Windows there's a couple of tricks to take care of...

(Assuming you've installed MySQL from Oracle's site but maybe have chosen not to run the service at startup)...

1. To use "mysqld stop" from the command line for WinVista/Win7 you must right click on Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> Command Prompt -> Run As Administrator
2. Now that you have local OS admin access you can use "mysqld stop" (which will simply return)

IF YOU SEE THE FOLLOWING YOU ARE TRYING IT WITH A USER/COMMAND PROMPT THAT DOES NOT HAVE THE CORRECT PRIVILEGES:

```
121228 11:54:50 [Warning] Can't create test file c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\hpdv7.lower-test
121228 11:54:50 [Warning] Can't create test file c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\hpdv7.lower-test
121228 11:54:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121228 11:54:50 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121228 11:54:50 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121228 11:54:50 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121228 11:54:50 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
121228 11:54:50 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121228 11:54:50  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.
InnoDB: File name .\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

If mysqld does not appear as a known system command, try adding it to your class path

1. Right click on My Computer
2. Advanced System Settings
3. Environment Variables
4. System variables
5. look for and left click select the variable named path
6. click on "Edit" and copy out the string to notepad and append at the end the full path to your MySQL bin directory , e.g.

   %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin

Answer (score 6):

I'm on XP. I've installed MySQL-5.6.10 manually from `.zip`, no Windows auto-installer provided by MySQL site. The `/bin` directory of my MySQL is in my PATH. So I start the server with `mysqld --console` command, like this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\User>mysqld --console
2013-04-12 14:39:19 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_times
tamp server option (see documentation for more details).
```

From now on it is running. And that cmd window is occupied. I open and use another one.

I've tried to use the answers from above but none of them can stop the server. Only errors are throw. So I stop the server with `mysqladmin -u root shutdown` on the other cmd window or with `Ctrl + C` on the cmd window it is running in. The latter works not so good as the former, sometimes I have to click `Ctrl + C` twice or more.

The log of the shutdown process is like this:

```
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Binlog end
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INSERTED'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2013-04-12 17:55:29 3968 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2013-04-12 17:55:30 3968 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1719777
2013-04-12 17:55:30 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2013-04-12 17:55:30 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2013-04-12 17:55:30 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2013-04-12 17:55:30 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2013-04-12 17:55:30 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2013-04-12 17:55:30 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2013-04-12 17:55:30 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2013-04-12 17:55:30 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2013-04-12 17:55:30 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2013-04-12 17:55:30 3968 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2013-04-12 17:55:30 3968 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

And I still don't know if it is 100% right way to shutdown the server, but it works :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a newer and easier answer.

1. Run cmd as admin
2. Type "net start mysql" then the version number, in my case "net start mysql80" for MySQL 8.0.
3. If it says it's already running great, otherwise now mysql is running.
4. Exit cmd, WIN+R and type services.msc, scroll down until you find my sql with the right version.
5. Right-Click for properties, under startup type select 'Manual', then under service status select 'Stop'
6. Now you stopped mysql service and it will not run automatically again.
7. To turn it back on, in cmd admin 'net start mysql' and the version number, in my case 'net start mysql80'

Answer (score 3):

to stop the service:

`sc stop mysql56`

and to start it:

`sc start mysql56`

you might need to change the `mysql56` to whatever your version is.

Answer (score 3):

On windows 10

If you wanna close it open command prompt with work with admin. Write `NET STOP MySQL80`. Its done.  If you wanna open again so you must write `NET START MySQL80`

*If you do not want it to be turned on automatically when not in use, it automatically runs when the computer is turned on and consumes some ram.*

Open **services.msc** find **Mysql80** , look at properties and turn start type manuel or otomaticly again as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running windows try this:

1. click start button on a keyboard
2. type task manager
3. right click and click run as administrator 
   when the task manager opens
4. click on services then look for MySQL then
5. right click on it then click stop
   then close task manager and you are done.

to start it when you wand to use it, follow the same steps and click start this time

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to shutdown mySQL server for Windows7 :

*My Computer > Manage > Services and Application > Services > select "MySQL 56"*(the name depends upon the version of MySQL installed.)
three options are present at left top corner. 
Stop the Service
pause the Service 
Restart the Service

choose Stop the service > to stop the server

Again to start you can come to the same location or we can chose tools options on mySQL GUI
*Server > Startup/Shutdown > Choose to Startup or Shutdown*

PS: some times it is not possible to stop the server from the GUI even though the options are provided. so is the reason the above alternative method is provided.

share the ans. to improve. 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

To successfully stop MySQL Service on Windows

1. Check on services the name of the service for MySQL
2. Run as administrator : `net stop [MySQL Service name]`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and here my solution:

1. go to service.msc and find mysql service. set it as start manually.
2. go to task manager - processes tab and find mysqld. stop it
3. go to task manager - services tab find mysql service and stop it

Answer (score 0):

As people already explained,

1. In windows, open **Command Prompt** as **Administrator**
2. if you're using MySQL 8.0

   net start mysql80       - to start MySQL

   **net stop mysql80**    - to stop MySQL

(if you're using MySQL 5.7 then **net stop mysql57**, similar for other versions)

**(Additional method)** - via bat file

just in case, if you forget the command often and want to do it via few clicks instead of opening command prompt and typing command every time,

1. open notepad type,

   **cmd /k net stop mysql80**
2. save as **stop_mysql.bat**
3. right click on file 'stop_mysql.bat', run as Administrator to run the MySQL stop command. This will run above stop command to stop MySQL
4. You can also create another bat file for starting MySQL with the other command

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

just type exit

and u are out of mysql in cmd in windows