# How to kill all the MySQL process in window

Tags: mysql, windows, shutdown

I'm using win10 and I have MySQL workbench 8.0 CE. I am trying to run my SQL script to check if there's any error but after I created the SQL forward engineering script and close anything about MySQL and reopen it and tried to run the script file it shows

> [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\Ozcar\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps2jek87r.cnf'

I tried to end anything about mySQL in task manager and I use cmd to do `net stop MySQL8.0` and `net start MySQL8.0` also but is still not work

How am I kill all the SQL processes and restart them properly?

Thank you for everyone who answer me.

Comment: did you try this? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57751883/8575615)

Comment: ya I did. After I stop everything and restart MySQL Workbench 8.0 and try to run the scruipt it shows the same thing